# Pandas: add column with progressive count of elements meeting a condition

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

Given the following dataframe `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Tony', 'Mike', 'Jen', 'Anna'], 'B': ['no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes']})

    A    B
0   Tony no 
1   Mike yes
2   Jen  no
3   Anna yes
```

I want to add another column that counts, progressively, the elements with `df['B']='yes'`:

```
    A    B   C
0   Tony no  0
1   Mike yes 1
2   Jen  no  0
3   Anna yes 2
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of boolean mask:

```
m = df['B']=='yes'
df['C'] = np.where(m, m.cumsum(), 0)
```

Another solution is `count` boolean mask created by filtering and then add `0` values by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
m = df['B']=='yes'
df['C'] = m[m].cumsum().reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
print (df)
      A    B  C
0  Tony   no  0
1  Mike  yes  1
2   Jen   no  0
3  Anna  yes  2
```

**Performance** (in real data should be different, best check it first):

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 10000
L = ['yes','no']
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': np.random.choice(L, N)})
print (df)

In [150]: %%timeit
     ...: m = df['B']=='yes'
     ...: df['C'] = np.where(m, m.cumsum(), 0)
     ...: 
1.57 ms ± 34.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [151]: %%timeit
     ...: m = df['B']=='yes'
     ...: df['C'] = m[m].cumsum().reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
     ...: 
2.53 ms ± 54.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [152]: %%timeit
     ...: df['C'] = df.groupby('B').cumcount() + 1
     ...: df['C'].where(df['B'] == 'yes', 0, inplace=True)

4.49 ms ± 27.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GroupBy` + `cumcount` followed by `pd.Series.where`:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('B').cumcount() + 1
df['C'].where(df['B'] == 'yes', 0, inplace=True)

print(df)

      A    B  C
0  Tony   no  0
1  Mike  yes  1
2   Jen   no  0
3  Anna  yes  2
```

Comment: Great answer, because it works even if you are trying to solve the same problem with a column that is not binary